# SpringBoot Application exit code get in Script file

Tags: java, bash, spring-boot, shell, sh

I have spring boot Application with below exit code

```
logger.info("Exiting Application with code:{}",exitCode);
return SpringApplication.exit(context,{}->exitCode);
```

where exitCode = 1 in case of error

I am executing this application(with error condition) in shell script with java -jar command in say abc.sh file

```
java -jar myApp.jar
echo $?
```

Here I am getting 0 as exitCode
but in log file showing Exiting Application with code:1.

Please help to get exit code from Spring boot Application in shell script.
Thanks in advance